# Python difference between randn and normal

Tags: python, numpy

I'm using the `randn` and `normal` functions from Python's `numpy.random` module. The functions are pretty similar from what I've read in the http://docs.scipy.org manual (they both concern the Gaussian distribution), but are there any subtler differences that I should be aware of? If so, in what situations would I be better off using a specific function?

Comment: They seem different to me. `normal`: Draw random samples from a normal (Gaussian) distribution. `randn`:  Return a random matrix with data from the “standard normal” distribution

Comment: @hughdbrown Same distribution, slightly different way of usage.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

`randn` seems to give a distribution from some standardized normal distribution (mean 0 and variance 1). `normal` takes more parameters for more control. So `randn` seems to simply be a convenience function.

Comment: They call the same C-function (`rk_gauss`) in the end. I think `randn` exists mainly to make MATLAB converts happy. The MATLAB `randn` seems to be more or less identical.

Comment: Ahh, in what file are they defined? I figured that was the case and looked a bit in the source, but i wasn't able to find it.

Comment: `numpy/random/mtrand/distributions.c`

Answer (score 67):

## Description

Looking at the docs that you linked in your question, I'll highlight some of the key differences:

normal:

```
numpy.random.normal(loc=0.0, scale=1.0, size=None)
# Draw random samples from a normal (Gaussian) distribution.

# Parameters :  
# loc : float -- Mean (“centre”) of the distribution.
# scale : float -- Standard deviation (spread or “width”) of the distribution.
# size : tuple of ints -- Output shape. If the given shape is, e.g., (m, n, k), then m * n * k samples are drawn.
```

So in this case, you're generating a ***GENERIC*** normal distribution (more details on what that means later).

randn:

```
numpy.random.randn(d0, d1, ..., dn)
# Return a sample (or samples) from the “standard normal” distribution.

# Parameters :  
# d0, d1, ..., dn : int, optional -- The dimensions of the returned array, should be all positive. If no argument is given a single Python float is returned.
# Returns : 
# Z : ndarray or float -- A (d0, d1, ..., dn)-shaped array of floating-point samples from the standard normal distribution, or a single such float if no parameters were supplied.
```

In this case, you're generating a ***SPECIFIC*** normal distribution, the standard distribution.

## (Brief) Math

Now some of the math, which is really needed to get at the heart of your question:

A normal distribution is a distribution where the values are **more likely** to occur near the mean value.  There are a bunch of cases of this in nature.  E.g., the average high temperature in Dallas in June is, let's say, 95 F.  It might reach 100, or even 105 average in one year, but it more typically will be near 95 or 97.  Similarly, it might reach as low as 80, but 85 or 90 is more likely.

So, it is fundamentally different from, say, a uniform distribution (rolling an honest 6-sided die).

---

A **standard** normal distribution is just a normal distribution where the average value is 0, and the variance (the mathematical term for the variation) is 1.

So,

```
numpy.random.normal(size= (10, 10))
```

is the exact same thing as writing

```
numpy.random.randn(10, 10)
```

because the **default** values (loc= 0, scale= 1) for `numpy.random.normal` are in fact the **standard** distribution.

## History

To make matters more confusing, as the [numpy random documentation](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/generated/numpy.random.randn.html) states:

```
sigma * np.random.randn(...) + mu
```

is the same as

```
np.random.normal(loc= mu, scale= sigma, ...)
```

---

The problem is really specialization: in statistics, Gaussian distributions are *so* common that terminology cropped up to enable discussions:

- Many distributions are Gaussain, so many that Gaussian became considered the **normal** distribution.
- Good modeling, especially linear modeling, requires that all elements are "of the same size" (similar mean and variance). So it became **standard** practice to rescale distributions to `mean=0` and `variance=1`.

---

*Final note:  I used the term variance to mathematically describe variation.  Some folks say standard deviation.  Variance simply equals the square of standard deviation.  Since the variance = 1 for the standard distribution, in this case of the standard distribution, `variance == standard deviation`.

Comment: Your answer seems interesting. But, how one can generate noise if measurement, say, is speed of something? Noise should contain only positive values..?! If it is the case, normal distribution can not generate positive value, right?

Comment: I'm not sure I'm following, @Spider .  If I'm following you, you're asking how values can be below the mean, too.  The definition of standard deviation is the variation AROUND the mean.  That is, both above and below it.  Not enough space here to get into it, but check out  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_deviation  or  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution

Comment: Oh, now I get what you were saying:  yes, a "speed" (not velocity, which is a vector) must only have positive numbers.  And yes, a normal distribution allows for negative numbers.  Therefore, as your intuition is already telling you, a speed does not follow a normal distribution.  There are many other types of distributions, such as Poisson or Binomial.

Comment: How is it possible to just scale the value given by randn with some value and it acts as though it is sigma? The definition of the normal distribution does not seem to allow such a simple scaling.

Comment: @Nimi Yes, the [definition of normal distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution#General_normal_distribution) does follow, when you perform variable substitution.  (Especially read the part about going from X to Z and vice versa in that linked section.)  The only "problem" is that a *magical* `1/sigma` appears outside the exponent.  This is to scale the entire integral so that the probability ***density*** scales to allow for the ***probability*** to equal 1 when integrating over all space.

Comment: @MikeWilliamson  the last link you have is out of date

Comment: @ComputerScientist Very likely... I wrote it over 3 years ago.  I will update it now, but I think we all need to accept that links are helpful, but not permanent, and that is why explanations should drive these answers at SO, and not let only links do the talking.  ;)

Comment: There is also a numpy.random.standard_normal function.

Answer (score 1):

Following up to @Mike Williamson's explanation about variance, standard deviation, I was caught trying to workout the example provided in the [Numpy documentation for randn](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.random.randn.html)
The example provided there:

```py
>>> import numpy as np
>>> 2.5 * np.random.randn(2, 4) + 3
array([[-1.13788245,  2.54061141, -0.12769502,  7.46200906],
       [-0.4780766 ,  1.70417835,  5.43802441,  4.71764135]])
```

The point to note here is that Normal Distribution follows notation N(Mean, Variance), whereas to implement using `.randn()` you would require to multiply the **standard deviation** or **sigma** and add the **Mean** or **mu** to the Standard Normal Output of the Numpy method(s).

Note:

`sqrt(Variance) = Standard Deviation or sigma`

Eg.,

`sqrt(6.25) = 2.5`

Hence:

`sigma * numpy.random.randn(2, 4) + mean`

Comment: Don't post images of text.

Comment: @RalfFriedl Fixed.